# How to reset the form after confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This code is a Travel Form, I want to reset all inputs form after confirmation (Radios, Checkbox, Text).
How to force the user to fill all input fields before submission?
I hope you will help me. Kind Regards.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var a = $('#first').val();
    var b = $('#last').val();
    var c = $('#age').val();
    var d = $('#male').val();
    var e = $('input[name=radAnswer]:checked').attr('id');
    var f = $('input[name=che1]:checked').attr('id');
    var z = [];

    if ($('#Vegetarian').is(':checked'))
        z.push($('#Vegetarian').val());

    if ($('#Kosher').is(':checked'))
        z.push($('#Kosher').val());

    if ($('#Masters').is(':checked'))
        z.push($('#Masters').val());

    $.confirm({
        animation: 'news',
        closeAnimation: 'news',
        theme: 'supervan',
        title: 'Confirm! Are you sure to Continue?',
        content: "First name: " + "&nbsp" +
            a + "<br>" + "Last name: " + "&nbsp" + b + "<br>" + "Age: " + 
"&nbsp" + c + "<br>" + "Gender: " + "&nbsp" + e + "<br>" + "Traveling to: " 
+ "&nbsp" + f + "<br>" + "Food type: " + "&nbsp" + z,

        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {
                $.alert('Confirmed!<br><br>Kind Regards.');
            },
            cancel: function () {
                $.alert('You Canceled!!!, Travel to Hell :)');
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: My Form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text inputs, you can use `$.val("")`. For checkboxes and radio buttons, use `$.attr("checked", false)`

You can add this into your code where you want it to clear the inputs:

```
$("input[type='text']").val("");
$("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", false);
```

If you're using the form in conjunction with an AJAX script, make sure that you clear the inputs after it's been sent through.

Comment: $("#first").val("");
$("#last").val("");
$("#age").val("");
document.getElementById("Male").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Female").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Istanbul").checked = false;
document.getElementById("New York").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Costa Rica").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Vegetarian").checked = false; document.getElementById("Kosher").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Masters").checked = false;

Comment: Thank you so much for help
and thanks for everyone tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

For your reset issue you can look at: http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/
TL;DR - `$('#yourFormId').trigger("reset");`
As for the validation, you can prevent submitting a form by adding the `required` attribute to each input field. e.g. `<input type="text" name="name" required>`.
Thou, it depends on your form markup in your HTML.

Comment: @ahmed.fager can you please provide your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

To reset form use `$('formElementId').reset()`.
To prevent form submit put `required` attribute on input's and use `$('formElementId').submit(//put your handler here)` instead of `click`.